# PHP Codeigniter: $data variables available to view in print_r but direct access gives 'undefined index' error

Tags: php, codeigniter

See last code block for controller code. When I use the line below in my view, it returns all the variables in the property array:

```
<?php echo print_r($property);?>
```

However, when I want to access just one item from the $property array, I get an undefined index error:

```
<?php echo print_r($property['county']);?>
```

Here is a var_dump ($property)

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'property_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'address1' => string '26 College Green Walk' (length=21)
      'town_city' => string 'Derby' (length=5)
      'county' => string 'Derbyshire' (length=10)
      'property_description' => string '<p>
    This is a property description for a rental property in Mickleover. Very nice it is too!</p>
' (length=100)
      'property_images_filepath' => string 'ee736-6.jpg' (length=11)
```

Can anyone point where to look because I'm stumped!?

The controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('agency_model');


    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
}



/**
 * Shows the details of the property specified by the $id parameter
 * @param string $id the id of the property to be retrieved from the DB
 */
public function show () {


$id = $this->input->get('property_id');


    if (!isset($id)) 
    {

        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }


    else

    {

        $data['property'] = $this->agency_model->get_property_details($id);
        $data['title'] = 'Current Properties';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('agency/property_details_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

}
```

}

Thanks
Gareth

Comment: Not sure that it matters but you didnt close the bracket around the array. I understand that this isnt the issue you are facing but I just had to point it out `<?php echo print_r($property['county']);?>` <-- fixed

Comment: @Cameeob2003 Good fix, made the change...still doesn't get me my variables though :-(

Comment: Can you post a var_dump of $property?

Comment: @Kisaragi Updated to include var_dump - you can see I have the variables available to the view to use like this, can't understand the error when I try to access them individually

Comment: what does print_r($propery[0]['county']) yield?

Comment: @Kisaragi Ah ha!! Now we're talking! That gives me what I'd expect - thank you kindly. Any idea why this is (just for my sanity)? When I'm looping through (as I'm doing on another page, which returns the list of properties) I can access the variables just using $property['county'] - I don't get why this is different. Any way, I can work with this and you've fixed my problem, thanks again.

Comment: Are you returning $query->result() or $query->row()?

Comment: @Kisaragi $query->result_array() actually, which I just copied from another function where I access the results with a for each loop in my view. So, I think this is the issue, reading the CI docs result_array() 'is typically used with a for each loop'. Though I'm not sure I understand why I need to use the array index when accessing the results through a for each vs non-loop access? Thanks for you input btw

Comment: In fact, if I use $query->result() or $query->row() and remove the the array index from the reference in the view, I get undefined index errors again...so still none the wiser! At least I've got a way to make this work though

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.
if your array is like this in controller

```
$data['info'] = array(
    'col_1' => "first_1",
     'col_2'=>  "first_2"
);
$this->load->view('folder/page',$data);
```

then in view you may access it like this.

```
echo $info['col_1'];
echo $info['col_1'];
```

Or if it is multiple record's array you will use

```
foreach($info as $row)
{
 //your code/statements.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's syntax error, did you mean:

```
<?php echo print_r($property['country');?>
```

and not:

```
<?php echo print_r($property['county');?>
```

Comment: No it's correct - good spot though! It's an English thing - a county is like a province or kind of like a state (I guess). I've tried it with other variables in the array too like `'town_city'` - still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will give you what you want

```
 foreach ($property as $properties)
     print_r($properties['county']);
 endforeach;
```

Comment: I only have one property on this page (it is a details view) so no need for a loop. The individual property is selected from the DB based on the property_id passed in $_GET Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to miss, but the following will work.

```
<?php echo print_r( $property[ 0 ]['county'] ); ?>
```

When you did a var_dump, I noticed that there was an array index.